MUI X Data Grid - Filtering after updateRows
I am working with MUI X Data Grid Premium v6. When I make an update to multiple rows programmatically using apiRef.current.updateRows() and then immediately use the <GridToolBarFilterButton /> component to filter for those updates, the updated rows are not included in the filtered rows. It's as if the filter component is using cached data from before the updates to the data grid were made. What's weird is that the grid updates appropriately in the UI with the changes using the updateRows() method. So the grid IS being updated, just not according to the filter. I can't find anything in the docs that addresses this and I'm wondering if I'm missing something or if I just found a bug?

Please create a sandbox. Will be easier to visualize.
